# Exclude a word from the view field

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a view that has two fields. In one of them I load the name of the term, but I want to remove want part of that name. So, the view has to load the name of the term, but without a part.

E. g. an article belongs to the term "Example - one" and I want it to show only "Example" part of the term name, i. e. before this " - ..." part.

Answer (score 0):

***--Edit--***
OK so since that **last** part is always the same, e.g. `Example one - something` and `Another example - something`, just do the same thing as below except use the length of  `- something` (spaces included), and make that number (in this case, **12**) a negative number.

Short version: use **-12** instead of **7**.

```
<?php
  print substr($value, 0, -12);
?>
```

***--End edit--***

There are several options, depending on how constant the terms themselves are. For example, do all the terms start with the same word (***Example** - one*, ***Example** - ninety-nine*, ***Example***, etc)? If so, you should see an option when configuring the field to "Trim this field to a maximum length", and in the case of the word *Example*, you'd just set that length to 7 (since there are 7 letters in the word *Example*).

You could also install the views_php module, add a new PHP field to the view (*Global: PHP* -- right under the *Global: custom text* option), then towards the bottom of the PHP field's configuration you should see a box for *Value* and another one below that for *Output*.

Set the *Value* of the PHP field like so:

```
return $row->term_field_goes_here;
```

... replacing *term_field_goes_here* with the appropriate "replacement pattern" you see under the *Value* box. Then set the *Output* of the PHP field like this:

```
<?php
  // $value is automatically assigned from the "Value" box, so we just tell it to
  //   print a substring of $value, aka $row->term_field_goes_here, keeping only 7
  //   characters, and starting from the 0th character ("E").
  print substr($value, 0, 7);
?>
```

Hope that helps... :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. They all start with different words, that is the problem, but the other part is always the same (" - something"). I want to remove that " - something". As far as I understand both of the codes you provided are used if the first part is the same.